# how should i refactor a piece of code that is present in many different functions, but has return statement in it

Tags: python, django, refactoring

The code snippet is coming from django view code, but it doesn't matter much.

Let's say I have the following piece of code...

```
def unsubscribe(request):
  #start of block
  user = request.user
  sid = request.POST.get('subscription_id')
  try:
    sub = Subscription.objects.get(id=sid)
  except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    return ajax_response(False, [('subscription', 'Given subscription does not exist.')])
  if sub.user != user:
    return ajax_response(False, [('subscription', 'Invalid permission.')])
  #end of block.
  sub.is_active = False
  sub.save()
  return ajax_response(True)
```

and say, I have another function `resubscribe()` that does exactly same thing as the above function, except it does `sub.is_active = True`.

In that case, what would be the best way to organize the code, so that code between `#block` and `#endblock` aren't duplicated? I guess in general, this question can be written as:

> There's a block of code that is copy-and-pasted over many different functions. however, this block of code contains `return` statement. in that case, what would be the best way to abstract this piece of logic out?

EDIT: fixed code snippet.

EDIT2: Actually, the easy way to solve this question is by creating a function say, toggle_active_status, which takes `request` and a boolean. (I figured it out after posting out the question).

However, i'm wondering about the case where the different logic between the functions is more than 1 line... like, say, code between #block and #endlbock only does input validation, and potentially any arbitrary application logic can come after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple options that haven't been shown yet:

Since this is a verification routine, use exceptions to indicate failure, and a normal None (ignored) return to indicate success:

```
def verify_permissions(request):
  user = request.user
  sid = request.POST.get('subscription_id')
  try:
    sub = Subscription.objects.get(id=sid)
  except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    raise PermissionError, 'Given subscription does not exist.'
  if sub.user != user:
    raise PermissionError, 'Invalid permission.'

def subscribe(request):
  try:
    verify_permissions(request)
    sub.save()
    return ajax_response(True)
  except PermissionError, why:
    return ajax_response(False, [('subscription', why)])
```

Or, since Python is dynamically typed and it's apparently OK to call `ajax_response` in a couple different ways: return the arguments used to construct the response, and check the value of the first one.

```
def verify_permissions(request, purpose):
  user = request.user
  sid = request.POST.get('subscription_id')
  try:
    sub = Subscription.objects.get(id=sid)
  except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    return (False, [(purpose, 'Given subscription does not exist.')]) 
  if sub.user != user:
    return (False, [(purpose, 'Invalid permission.')])
  return (True,)

def subscribe(request):
  result = verify_permissions(request, 'subscription')
  if result[0]: sub.save()
  return ajax_response(*result)
```

Comment: I actually like your suggestion... Let's see how this question goes.

Answer (score 3):

Factor out the duplicated chunk and have the difference be passed in, creating wrapper functions that pass in the difference:

```
def alter_subscription(request, make_active):
  # start of block
  # (...)
  # end of block
  sub.is_active = make_active
  sub.save()
  return ajax_response(True)

def unsubscribe(request):
  return alter_subscription(request, False)

def resubscribe(request):
  return alter_subscription(request, True)
```

Comment: If the common code is only doing validation, call it from the wrapper(s) and check the return value.  If this is a django question and you're trying to do validation, maybe look at middleware or a decorator?

Comment: But don't call the parameter "`bool`", because that masks a builtin (the name of the type). :)

Comment: fixed (re: "bool")  ty, Karl.  :)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to simply create a separate function containing the duplicated functionality. You can use the parameters of the function to introduce the necessary differences.

If the code snippet returns something, then you might use a convention, such as to return `None` if the function should not return, or an object otherwise. In your caller function, just test whether the returned parameter is `None` or not, and return the returned variable if it isn't `None`.

Comment: i've actually thought of it, and created the function `def _toggle_subscription(request, toggle_to):` which has the line `sub.is_active = toggle_to`... but i feel like i've exploited the fact that this example has such a small differences between the provided codes. What if the difference between the two functions are conisiderable?

Comment: Well, if the difference is considerable, I don't think that counts as code duplication.

Comment: Sorry, i guess i wasn't being specific... when i refer to the "difference" i meant to point out at the difference between the non-common logics. in the provided example, the difference between subscribe() and unsubscribe() will be sub.is_active = False(or True). However, what if the code between #block and #endblock are just preliminary checks, and the actual logic that follows is more complicated?

Comment: In the more complex cases, you can try the second suggestion with the conventional 'None' result. Or try my suggestion. :)